# Show parsed html block randomly with Simple Html Dom

Tags: php, html, parsing, simple-html-dom

Page which I need to parse has items with id="item". There are about 10 items on the page. I need to parse them all and show in random order on my page.

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
<br>
$data1 = file_get_html('http://linktowebsite.com';
<br>
if($data1->innertext!='' and count($data1->find('.item'))) {
    <br>
    foreach($data1->find('.item') as $a) {
        <br>
        echo $a;
    }
}
```

this code parses but didn't shows in random order. Help me please to show them in random order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect the items, and then apply randomization.

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$data1 = file_get_html('http://linktowebsite.com';
$items = array();
if($data1->innertext!='' and count($data1->find('.item'))){
    foreach($data1->find('.item') as $a){
        $items[] = $a;
    }
}
shuffle($items); // randomize
print_r($items);
```

You could also use `array_rand` or `usort` with a random sort callback.

```
usort($items, "rand"); // I think this works
```

Comment: I have tried this,but got only text like this in output:
Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 1 [tag] => li [attr] => Array ( [class] => cart ) [children] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 1 [tag] => a [attr] => Array ( [href] => http://royalcasesuae.com/?page_id=7 [title] => View your shopping cart [class] => cart-parent ) [children] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 1 [tag] => span [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 1 [tag] => span [attr]